# Spring Boot with GCP Postgres (IAM Auth) - Connection Failures

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to GCP Postgres DB using IAM Auth from a Springboot application.

Below is the code that I use to connect to Postgres DB

```
@Component
public class DbTest {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
    public void checkDbConnectivityEveryFiveMinutes() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Testing DB connectivity @ --- --- " + new Date());

            Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT 1");
            query.getSingleResult();

            System.out.println("DB connectivity test successful @ " + new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("DB connectivity test failed @ " + new Date() + " - " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The application is deployed into GCP Cloud Run, The GCP environment is inside a VPN, so I have provided Proxy configurations to the Cloud Run configurations, the application is working fine without any issues continuously for some days together. However, there is suddenly an exception happening like below,

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.lambda$list$0(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getMetaData(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getColumnCount(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.query.results.ResultSetMappingImpl.resolve(ResultSetMappingImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.resolveJdbcValuesSource(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.performList(NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:621)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:473)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:405)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy245.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.DbTest.checkDbConnectivityEveryFiveMinutes(DbTest.java:25)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:113)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:320)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: [XXXXXXXXX] Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.getInstanceData(CloudSqlInstance.java:165)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.createSslSocket(CloudSqlInstance.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.createSslSocket(CoreSocketFactory.java:329)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.connect(CoreSocketFactory.java:199)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:77)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: [XXXXXXXXX] Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:592)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:571)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:111)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SqlAdminApiFetcher.getInstanceData(SqlAdminApiFetcher.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.performRefresh(CloudSqlInstance.java:237)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:75)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [XXXXXXXXX] Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SqlAdminApiFetcher.addExceptionContext(SqlAdminApiFetcher.java:426)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SqlAdminApiFetcher.fetchEphemeralCertificate(SqlAdminApiFetcher.java:271)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SqlAdminApiFetcher.lambda$getInstanceData$1(SqlAdminApiFetcher.java:114)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CombinedFuture$CallableInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(CombinedFuture.java:196)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:75)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:152)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:552)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:493)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:603)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SqlAdminApiFetcher.fetchEphemeralCertificate(SqlAdminApiFetcher.java:269)
    ... 9 more
```

Once the error occurs, the application fails and we have to redeploy the application to recover from this error. We are not sure what could suddenly cause this error.

Below is my Datasource configurations,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///mydb?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=XXXXXXXXX
spring.datasource.username=<<my service account>>
spring.datasource.password=Using_IAM

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enable-iam-auth=true
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.ip-types=PRIVATE
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=mydb
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=XXXXXXXXX
spring.flyway.fail-on-missing-locations = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=<<myschema>>

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
```

I have a similar application deployed and running in GCP Cloud Run, which is running fine without any issues, no such error there.

Any thoughts on what could be the issue here with this application?